# Start service with LocationListener in foreground

Tags: android

I have a service that informs the user's location from time to time to the server. The service starts when the application is opened, but after a time if the phone lock screen the service is killed even with

```
OnStartCommand return START_STICKY.
```

Would it be right to start this service in the foreground?

Comment: Turning off the screen doesn't end services.  Running low on resources does, and running it foreground, even if you could (you'd need a notification to do so) would be unlikely to work.  What turning off the screen could do is invoke Doze, which would be a problem for a foreground service as well.

Comment: @GabeSechan Sorry, is when the screen is locked.

Comment: Answer doesn't change.  Services aren't closed when the screen is locked.  They could not be given the processor due to Doze, but they aren't killed.  And foreground and background services are treated the same in that respect.

Comment: So what to do for the service not to be killed?

Comment: You can't prevent the service from being killed.  If android thinks you need to be killed for resources, it will just do that.  The best you can do is return START_STICKY so you'll be restarted if resources return in the future.  There are ways to avoid Doze, but it requires the user to whitelist your app (you can't do it programmatically).  The first thing you need to do is figure out which is actually happening, because I assure you locking the screen isn't killing you.  If you're actually killed, its for another reason.